# How to get DB field from related Table with GPvar using Typoscript

Tags: typoscript, typo3-9.x

I'm using TYPO3 9.5 and want to get a field from a related table using Typoscript. I've tried different variation but non is working.

This is my last and from my point of view most promising approach that didn't work. I hope it at least helps to make clear what I'm aiming for:

```
1 = LOAD_REGISTER
1.param = TEXT
1.param.dataWrap = DB : tx_hproducts_domain_model_product:{GP:tx_hproducts_hproduct|id}:relation
1.param.wrap3 = {|}
1.param.insertData = 1
2 = CONTENT
2.table = tx_hproducts_domain_model_related
2.select {
  pidInList = 43
  orderBy = sorting
  where = uid = {REGISTER:param}
  where.insertData = 1
}
2.renderObj = COA
2.renderObj {
  10 = TEXT
  10.stdWrap.field = name
}
```

So in fact I get the procuts ID as a GetVar, select the ID of the record from the related DB. I a second step I want to select the name of the record from the related table.

Hope it's not to confusion and there is a solution for that.

Comment: Just curious, what is the purpose of using it like this?

Comment: I want to automatically create meta informations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the solution with TypoScript. In such case I would rather create some custom extension or even ViewHelper and code it with PHP, most probably it would be easier. Of course, it's just suffestion.

Comment: What's more, if _hproducts_ is your own extension you can do it easily within your plugin's controller.

Comment: Ahhhh. UserFunc?

Comment: USERFUNC, ViewHelper, controller, whatever, the main goal is moving it to PHP, as it will be just much more comfortable to maintain. When you'll do it, rest is rather an easy task, just created locally VH to check this concept and it works like a charm. Maybe you can use some other way, don't know your environment.

Comment: That’s great. I was so much into TS that I didn’t thought about that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217999/discussion-between-biesior-and-lufi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP, life will be better ;)

Assuming your vendor name is `LUFI` and extension key is `extkey` it can be something like this (of course I do not try to use your tables, instead getting some `tt_content` rows by hardcoded `uid`):

**typo3conf/ext/extkey/Classes/AdditionalHeaders.php**

```php
<?php
namespace LUFI\Extkey;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;

class AdditionalHeaders
{
    public function addHeaders()
    {
        /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder $queryBuilder */
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tt_content');

        $queryBuilder
            ->getRestrictions()
            ->removeAll();

        $res = $queryBuilder
            ->select('uid', 'pid', 'header')
            ->from('tt_content')
            ->where($queryBuilder
                ->expr()
                ->orX(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                        'pid',
                        $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('12', \PDO::PARAM_INT)
                    ),
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                        'pid',
                        $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('13', \PDO::PARAM_INT)
                    ),
                )
            )
            ->orderBy('sorting', 'ASC');

            // DebuggerUtility::var_dump($res->getSQL(), 'SQL', 8, false);
            // DebuggerUtility::var_dump($res->getParameters(), 'parameters');

        $statement = $res->execute();

        /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController $tsfe */
        $tsfe = $GLOBALS['TSFE'];

        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
            // make sure the index for additionalHeaderData is unique ie by adding UID of record
            $tsfe->additionalHeaderData['tt_content_meta' . $row['uid']] = '<meta name="some-header" content="' . $row['header'] . '"/>';
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**In Setup of your TypoScript Template:**

```
page.9999 = USER
page.9999 {
  userFunc = LUFI\Extkey\AdditionalHeaders->addHeaders
}
```